# Custom Scalar Value Types

Tags: mfc, protocol-buffers

I am currently trying to rewrite the network code of a MFC application to fit it to a new server, (written in c#) later on.
I'm experimenting with protobuf to ensure that all data models are the same.

My problem is, that the Scalar Value Types, protobuf works with is not understood by the MFC type system. It uses DWORD instead of uint32, BYTE instead of byte or bool and so on. That requires custom type mapping/casting and that's not necessarily taking work from my shoulders. 
Is there a way to change those datatypes used in protobuf?

A sample protobuf model would be:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package CInterop;

option csharp_namespace = "CCX.Protobuf.Login";

message LoginAck {
    LoginResultStatus Status = 1;
    uint32 dwUserID = 2;
    uint32 dwCharID = 3;
    uint32 dwKEY = 4;
    uint32 dwMapIP = 5;
    uint32 wPort = 6;
    uint32 bCharCreateCount = 7; 
    bool IsInPcRoom = 8;
    uint32 PremiumPcRoomValue = 9; 
    uint64 dCurrentTime = 10;

    uint64 dKey = 11;
    string Reason = 12;
    uint64 iDuration = 13;
    bool bEternal = 14;
  }
```

The current usage would be

```
CInterop::LoginAck loginAck;

(*pPacket) >> loginAck; // Reads the packet from the buffer

m_dwUserID = (DWORD)loginAck.dwuserid();
m_dwKickID = (DWORD)loginAck.dwcharid();
m_dwKEY = (DWORD)loginAck.dwkey();
vADDR.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = (ULONG)loginAck.dwmapip();
vADDR.sin_port = (USHORT)loginAck.wport();
m_bCreateCardCnt = (byte)loginAck.bcharcreatecount();
m_bInPCROOM = (BYTE)loginAck.isinpcroom();
m_dwPrmPCROOM = (DWORD)loginAck.premiumpcroomvalue();
```

But here, i don't want to cast the types, this should happen automatically somehow.

Comment: Normally I'd advocate just sticking a translation layer in the middle, meaning: one set of types that work with MFC, and another set of types that work with protobuf, that just look similar ish. However, if this is C# there may be some options with protobuf-net. Do you have a specific model example?

Comment: @MarcGravell Sorry that it took me so long to respond. I've added sample code. Can you show me how i could write such a wrapper in an convinient way? Another thing is, that there are around 800 packets. Writing 800 wrapper classes could become a pain in the ass.